# Creating a Dynamic Table?

Tags: android, dynamic, tablelayout

I am learning android development ,I want to create dynamic table rows .I don't know how to create .I want to create two table .One should static and Another should be dynamic .

I referred in internet and i saw table layout , recycler view and I don't know which is best way to do it.Please someone guid me.
I want to create a tables like this 
[image]

I have tried like this only
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply create table and rows as simple as in webpages. you have to use TableLayout,TableRow  and textview(for rendering text inside of it).
create no of textviews as cell and add it to TableRow(android layout) then add the tablerow and add it to TableLayout and then add tablelayout to root layout. On dynamic insertation invalidate the view to see changes

Comment: If you have any example please share with me .

Comment: shall i use a recycler view for this?

Comment: @siva Manoj, I'll give you the overview code tonight